# how to trigger done button event in ios 8 swift MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification?

Tags: ios, video, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

my code here:

in viewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doneButtonClick", name: MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification, object: nil)
```

my handler:

```
func doneButtonClick(sender:NSNotification?){
    println("finishPreload");
}

let player:MPMoviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController()
```

my MPMoviePlayerController:

```
let videoUrl = (json[0]["files"][0]["furl"]).string

self.player.view.frame  = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(self.player.view)

self.player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
self.player.controlStyle = .Fullscreen;
self.player.repeatMode = .One
self.player.contentURL = NSURL(string: videoUrl)
self.player.prepareToPlay()
self.player.play()
```

when i click the done button on the top left,the video is stopped,but the doneButtonClick method is not triggered,anyone can help ?i have tried **MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification** and **MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification** for serval times,both not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `"doneButtonClick"` function have one argument. So you should use `":"` after the function name.

ie; `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doneButtonClick:", name: MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification, object: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2 answer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MediaVideoController.moviePlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:)) , name: MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification, object: videoPlayerController)
}

func moviePlayerDidFinishPlaying(notification: NSNotification) {
    videoPlayerController.controlStyle = .None
}
```